# Difference between Lucene stemmers: EnglishStemmer, PorterStemmer, LovinsStemmer

Tags: java, lucene, stemming

Have anybody compared these stemmers from Lucene (package org.tartarus.snowball.ext):
EnglishStemmer, PorterStemmer, LovinsStemmer?
What are the strong/weak points of algorithms behind them?
When each of them should be used?
Or maybe there are some more algorithms available for english words stemming?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Lovins stemmer is a [very old](http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/lovins/stemmer.html) algorithm that is not of much practical use, since the Porter stemmer is much stronger. Based on some quick skimming of the source code, it seems `PorterStemmer` implements Porter's [original (1980) algorithm](http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/porter/stemmer.html), while `EnglishStemmer` implements his [updated version](http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/english/stemmer.html), which should be better.

A stronger stemming algorithm (actually a lemmatizer) is available in the Stanford NLP tools. A Lucene-Stanford NLP by yours truly bridge is available [here](https://github.com/larsmans/lucene-stanford-lemmatizer) ([API docs](http://larsmans.github.com/lucene-stanford-lemmatizer/)).

See also [Manning, Raghavan & Schütze](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html) for general info about stemming and lemmatization.

Comment: You're stemmer is GPL so it doesn't plug into the Apache Lucene Ecosystem very well.  Would you consider changing the license of your stemmer from GPL to Apache 2 so that more people can can use it?

Answer (score 1):

I've tested the [3 Lucene stemmers available from `org.apache.lucene.analysis.en` version 4.4.0](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/package-summary.html), which are `EnglishMinimalStemFilter`, `KStemFilter` and `PorterStemFilter`, in a document classification problem I'm working on.  My results corroborate the claims made by the authors of [Introduction to Information Retrieval](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html) that **for small training corpora in document classification settings stemming is harmful, and for large corpora stemming makes no difference**.

For search and indexing, stemming can be more useful (see, e.g., [Jenkins & Smith](http://www.uea.ac.uk/polopoly_fs/1.85493!stemmer25feb.pdf)), but even there the answer to your question depends on the details of what you're doing.  [There is no free lunch!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem)

At the end of the day, **nothing beats empirical tests of real code on real data**.  The only way you'll really know which is better is by running the stemmers for yourself in your application.