# How to remove the last character from a string?

Tags: java, string

I want to remove the last character from a string. I've tried doing this:

```
public String method(String str) {
    if (str.charAt(str.length()-1)=='x'){
        str = str.replace(str.substring(str.length()-1), "");
        return str;
    } else{
        return str;
    }
}
```

Getting the length of the string - 1 and replacing the last letter with nothing (deleting it), but every time I run the program, it deletes middle letters that are the same as the last letter.

For example, the word is "admirer"; after I run the method, I get "admie." I want it to return the word admire.

Answer (score 803, accepted):

`replace` will replace all instances of a letter. All you need to do is use [`substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)):

```
public String method(String str) {
    if (str != null && str.length() > 0 && str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == 'x') {
        str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: I'd add `null != str && ` at the beginning of the check.

Comment: you mean `str != null &&`!

Comment: @SSpoke it's the same thing, yours is just a little nicer to read :)

Comment: @Marko lol yes since  it's the standard, feels odd when people make their own stuff up.

Comment: @SSpoke @Marko I agree that yours is nicer to read SSpoke. The reason some people write it like VenomFangs did is that in some languages (I'm looking at you C) will allow you to write `str = null` in an if statement but not `null = str` so putting the null first stops you from making that mistake.

Comment: @GaryBuyn how does that stop you from making a mistake?

Comment: @AdamJensen In C you could accidentally write `if (str = NULL)` which will not only always evaluate to false (NULL == 0 == false) but will also assign a value to `str` which is most likely not what you wanted to do. You could not write `if (NULL = str)` however because NULL is not a variable and cannot be assigned to. So, it is a safer convention to put the NULL on the left. This isn't an issue in Java though.

Comment: If I am right this will take O(n) time, i.e. JVM is going to scan the whole list, not O(1) as in C/C++, where they just move '\0' value up?

Comment: @GaryBuyn C will warn you, or throw an error. see: -Wtautological-compare. So, it's completely save to use if( str = 0 ) these days...

Comment: `str.endsWith("x")` can also be used to find if the string `str` has a trailing `x`.

Comment: @GaryBuyn the fact that numbers and null pointers are not interpreted as boolean expressions in Java saves you anyway.

Comment: [beginner java guy here] can you really do str = str.something() ? I mean, I can see that it works but surely this must go against the concept of String being immutable?

Comment: @DraxDomax In the example above, `str.substring(...)` creates a new `String` instance (it does not modify the original `String` instance). Then, the new `String` is assigned to the variable `str`, replacing the original (again, not modifying it). The original would then be garbage collected assuming there are no other references to it.

Comment: /data/user/0/com.app.imaged/cache/file_picker/Screenshot_2022-05-16-20-59-27-37.jpg || how to remove " Screenshot_2022-05-16-20-59-27-37.jpg " this only , last file name ? i need folder only

Comment: It's obsolete now... `length()` is not a function anymore but the rest is working just replace `str.length()` with `str.length` and it will work well

Comment: @Raskul Really? As of Java 21, String.length() still exists and is not marked deprecated.

Answer (score 280):

Why not just one liner?

```
public static String removeLastChar(String str) {
    return removeChars(str, 1);
}

public static String removeChars(String str, int numberOfCharactersToRemove) {
    if(str != null && !str.trim().isEmpty()) {
        return str.substring(0, str.length() - numberOfCharactersToRemove);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Full Code

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String s1 = "Remove Last CharacterY";
        String s2 = "Remove Last Character2";
        String s3 = "N";
        String s4 = null;
        String s5 = "";
        System.out.println("After removing s1==" + removeLastChar(s1) + "==");
        System.out.println("After removing s2==" + removeLastChar(s2) + "==");
        System.out.println("After removing s3==" + removeLastChar(s3) + "==");
        System.out.println("After removing s4==" + removeLastChar(s4) + "==");
        System.out.println("After removing s5==" + removeLastChar(s5) + "==");
        }
    
    public static String removeLastChar(String str) {
        return removeChars(str, 1);
    }

    public static String removeChars(String str, int numberOfCharactersToRemove) {
        if(str != null && !str.trim().isEmpty()) {
            return str.substring(0, str.length() - numberOfCharactersToRemove);
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

### [Demo](https://ideone.com/Q6a3CC)

Comment: The check for null and empty string should be considered.. @BobBobBob version is better

Comment: @KDjava : above is valid with considering that valid string is passed. else I would have to add the try catch block also to check that string is correct...

Comment: i added check for null string before `return str.substring(0,str.length()-1);` as improvement

Comment: Thanks this source is in use at https://gist.github.com/CrandellWS/e254a215c54aa4be0400a3511a23f730

Comment: @FahimParkar: Because it may be possible that last character is not the character that we want to remove. But as per the question, your answer is correct

Answer (score 116):

Since we're on a subject, one can use regular expressions too

```
"aaabcd".replaceFirst(".$",""); //=> aaabc
```

Comment: nice way, when you want/need to define exactly what you want to trim from the end of the string, not just X whatever chars

Answer (score 99):

The described problem and proposed solutions sometimes relate to removing separators. If this is your case, then have a look at Apache Commons StringUtils, it has a method called [removeEnd](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#removeEnd-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) which is very elegant.

Example:

```
StringUtils.removeEnd("string 1|string 2|string 3|", "|");
```

Would result in:
"string 1|string 2|string 3"

Comment: Here's the JAR for the aforementioned StringUtils: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi

Answer (score 57):

```
public String removeLastChar(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
        return s;
    }
    return s.substring(0, s.length()-1);
}
```

Comment: What if the last character is a high/low surrogate pair?

Comment: @RobertAllanHenniganLeahy I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50768270/7098259) that handles that scenario.

Answer (score 41):

Don't try to reinvent the wheel, while others have already written libraries to perform string manipulation: 
[`org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.chop()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#chop%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: If you want to remove the last character ONLY - this is the best answer!

Comment: No it isn't, because "use Java" is a terrible answer to a Kotlin question.

Comment: @MikkelLøkke I don't know, but this question is not a Kotlin question in any case??

Answer (score 41):

In Kotlin you can used dropLast() method of the string class.
It will drop the given number from string, return a new string

```
var string1 = "Some Text"
string1 = string1.dropLast(1)
```

Answer (score 28):

Use this:

```
 if(string.endsWith("x")) {

    string= string.substring(0, string.length() - 1);
 }
```

Answer (score 11):

```
if (str.endsWith("x")) {
  return str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
}
return str;
```

---

> For example, the word is "admirer"; after I run the method, I get "admie." I want it to return the word admire.

In case you're trying to [stem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) English words

> Stemming is the process for reducing inflected (or sometimes derived) words to their stem, base or root form—generally a written word form.
>
> ...
>
> A stemmer for English, for example, should identify the string "cats" (and possibly "catlike", "catty" etc.) as based on the root "cat", and "stemmer", "stemming", "stemmed" as based on "stem". A stemming algorithm reduces the words "fishing", "fished", "fish", and "fisher" to the root word, "fish".

[Difference between Lucene stemmers: EnglishStemmer, PorterStemmer, LovinsStemmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068790/difference-between-lucene-stemmers-englishstemmer-porterstemmer-lovinsstemmer) outlines some Java options.

Answer (score 11):

As far as the readability is concerned, I find this to be the most concise

```
StringUtils.substring("string", 0, -1);
```

The negative indexes can be used in Apache's StringUtils utility.
All negative numbers are treated from offset from the end of the string.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is the best answer - for simplicity use org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.chop() method. Yet, the trick with -1 is really nice and looking at the other answers is not really used / well known.

Answer (score 8):

```
 string = string.substring(0, (string.length() - 1));
```

I'm using this in my code, it's easy and simple.
it only works while the String is > 0.
I have it connected to a button and inside the following *if* statement

```
if (string.length() > 0) {
    string = string.substring(0, (string.length() - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public String removeLastChar(String s) {
    if (!Util.isEmpty(s)) {
        s = s.substring(0, s.length()-1);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

removes last occurence of the 'xxx':

```
    System.out.println("aaa xxx aaa xxx ".replaceAll("xxx([^xxx]*)$", "$1"));
```

removes last occurrence of the 'xxx' if it is last:

```
    System.out.println("aaa xxx aaa  ".replaceAll("xxx\\s*$", ""));
```

you can replace the 'xxx' on what you want but watch out on special chars

Answer (score 4):

Look to StringBuilder Class :

```
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder("toto,");
    System.out.println(sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1));//display "toto"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 // creating StringBuilder
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(requestString);
 // removing last character from String
 builder.deleteCharAt(requestString.length() - 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

How can a simple task be made complicated. My solution is:

```
public String removeLastChar(String s) {
    return s[0..-1]
}
```

or

```
public String removeLastChar(String s) {
    if (s.length() > 0) {
        return s[0..-1]
    }
    return s
}
```

Comment: Is `s[0..-1]` java?

Comment: bruh.. this is not java

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner answer (just a *funny alternative* - do not try this at home, and great answers already given):

```
public String removeLastChar(String s){return (s != null && s.length() != 0) ? s.substring(0, s.length() - 1): s;}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Remove n last characters  
// System.out.println(removeLast("Hello!!!333",3));

public String removeLast(String mes, int n) {
    return mes != null && !mes.isEmpty() && mes.length()>n
         ? mes.substring(0, mes.length()-n): mes;
}

// Leave substring before character/string  
// System.out.println(leaveBeforeChar("Hello!!!123", "1"));

public String leaveBeforeChar(String mes, String last) {
    return mes != null && !mes.isEmpty() && mes.lastIndexOf(last)!=-1
         ? mes.substring(0, mes.lastIndexOf(last)): mes;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most answers here forgot about [***surrogate pairs***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903008/what-is-a-surrogate-pair-in-java).

For instance, the character  (codepoint U+1D56B) does not fit into a single `char`, so in order to be represented, it must form a surrogate pair of two chars.

If one simply applies the currently accepted answer (using `str.substring(0, str.length() - 1)`, one splices the surrogate pair, leading to unexpected results.

One should also include a check whether the last character is a surrogate pair:

```
public static String removeLastChar(String str) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(str, "The string should not be null");
    if (str.isEmpty()) {
        return str;
    }

    char lastChar = str.charAt(str.length() - 1);
    int cut = Character.isSurrogate(lastChar) ? 2 : 1;
    return str.substring(0, str.length() - cut);
}
```

Comment: On a corner case : can this ever throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` ? (e.g. is it possible that Character.isSurrogate returns true when there is actually no char before it, making `str.length()-cut` negative).

Comment: Yes, that's possible. It's an invalid string anyway, but still – it's possible, yes. One should then replace `2` by `Math.min(2, str.length())`.

Answer (score 1):

Java 8

```
import java.util.Optional;

public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
  {
    System.out.println(removeLastChar("test-abc"));
  }

  public static String removeLastChar(String s) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(s)
      .filter(str -> str.length() != 0)
      .map(str -> str.substring(0, str.length() - 1))
      .orElse(s);
    }
}
```

Output : test-ab

Answer (score 1):

```
public String removeLastCharacter(String str){
       String result = null;
        if ((str != null) && (str.length() > 0)) {
          return str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
        }
        else{
            return "";
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For kotlin check out

```
string.dropLast(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

if we want to remove file extension of the given file,

** Sample code

```
 public static String removeNCharactersFromLast(String str,int n){
    if (str != null && (str.length() > 0)) {
        return str.substring(0, str.length() - n);
    }

    return "";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have special character like ; in json just use String.replace(";", "") otherwise you must rewrite all character in string minus the last.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [escape sequence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) ... !

```
System.out.println(str + '\b');
```

Life is much easier now . XD ! ~ A readable one-liner

Comment: Isn't this Java. LMAO

Comment: Special behaviour of '\b' is interpreted by string reader, text terminals etc.. otherwise it's just another ASCII character representation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11891895/4589003

Answer (score 0):

I had to write code for a similar problem. One way that I was able to solve it used a recursive method of coding.

```
static String removeChar(String word, char charToRemove)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < word.lenght(); i++)
    {
        if(word.charAt(i) == charToRemove)
        {
            String newWord = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i + 1);
            return removeChar(newWord, charToRemove);
        }
    }

    return word;
}
```

Most of the code I've seen on this topic doesn't use recursion so hopefully I can help you or someone who has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

How to make the char in the recursion at the end:

```
public static String  removeChar(String word, char charToRemove)
    {
        String char_toremove=Character.toString(charToRemove);
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            if(word.charAt(i) == charToRemove)
            {
                String newWord = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i + 1);
                return removeChar(newWord,charToRemove);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(word);
        return word;
    }
```

for exemple:

```
removeChar ("hello world, let's go!",'l') → "heo word, et's go!llll"
removeChar("you should not go",'o') → "yu shuld nt goooo"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that works with codepoints outside of the Basic Multilingual Plane (Java 8+).

Using streams:

```
public String method(String str) {
    return str.codePoints()
            .limit(str.codePoints().count() - 1)
            .mapToObj(i->new String(Character.toChars(i)))
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

More efficient maybe:

```
public String method(String str) {
    return str.isEmpty()? "": str.substring(0, str.length() - Character.charCount(str.codePointBefore(str.length())));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace the condition of "if" like this:

```
if(a.substring(a.length()-1).equals("x"))'
```

this will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose total length of my string=24
I want to cut last character after position 14 to end, mean I want starting 14 to be there.
So I apply following solution.

```
String date = "2019-07-31T22:00:00.000Z";
String result = date.substring(0, date.length() - 14);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy Peasy:

```
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
for(Entry<String,String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        sb.append(entry.getKey() + "_" + entry.getValue() + "|");
}
String requiredString = sb.substring(0, sb.length() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 8 you can use Optional to avoid null pointer exceptions and use functional programming:

```
public String removeLastCharacter(String string) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(string)
        .filter(str -> !str.isEmpty() && !string.isBlank())
        .map(str -> str.substring(0, str.length() - 1))
        .orElse(""); // Should be another value that need if the {@param: string} is "null"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is well known problem solved beautifully in Perl via chop() and chomp()

long answer here : [Java chop and chomp](https://myriad.website/java-chop-and-chomp/)

here is the code :

```
  //removing trailing characters
  public static String chomp(String str, Character repl) {
    int ix = str.length();
    for (int i=ix-1; i >= 0; i-- ){
      if (str.charAt(i) != repl) break;
      ix = i;
    }
    return str.substring(0,ix);
  }
  
  //hardcut  
  public static String chop(String str) {
    return str.substring(0,str.length()-1);
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

This is the one way to remove the last character in the string:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = in.nextLine();
char array[] = s.toCharArray();
int l = array.length;
for (int i = 0; i < l-1; i++) {
    System.out.print(array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

u can do i
hereString =  hereString.replace(hereString.chatAt(hereString.length() - 1) ,' whitespeace');

Answer (score -3):

Use StringUtils.Chop(Str) it also takes care of null and empty strings, u need to import common-io:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I think that is not necessary to add an external library for a simple feature like this.