# Remove the last chars of the Java String variable

Tags: java, string

A java String variable whose value is

```
String path = "http://cdn.gs.com/new/downloads/Q22010MVR_PressRelease.pdf.null"
```

I want to remove the last four characters i.e., `.null`. Which method I can use in order to split.

Comment: Man, the `String` class itself has all required methods. Just type `path.` and spend 2 minutes looking at the code completion options. Really, habit to learn will pay in future 100 times.

Comment: .null is 5 chars

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the last character from a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438612/how-to-remove-the-last-character-from-a-string)

Comment: @Nateowami `.null` if 5 characters, not 1. Also, the top answer in this question better addresses the problem that any of those answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 143, accepted):

I think you want to remove the last *five* characters ('.', 'n', 'u', 'l', 'l'):

```
path = path.substring(0, path.length() - 5);
```

Note how you need to use the return value - strings are immutable, so `substring` (and other methods) don't change the existing string - they return a reference to a *new* string with the appropriate data.

Or to be a bit safer:

```
if (path.endsWith(".null")) {
  path = path.substring(0, path.length() - 5);
}
```

However, I would try to tackle the problem higher up. My guess is that you've only got the ".null" because some other code is doing something like this:

```
path = name + "." + extension;
```

where `extension` is null. I would conditionalise that instead, so you never get the bad data in the first place.

(As noted in a question comment, you really should look through the [`String` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). It's one of the most commonly-used classes in Java, so there's no excuse for not being familiar with it.)

Comment: "I would try to tackle the problem higher up." is the most "correct" answer imo

Answer (score 38):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

// path = "http://cdn.gs.com/new/downloads/Q22010MVR_PressRelease.pdf.null"
StringUtils.removeEnd(path, ".null");
// path = "http://cdn.gs.com/new/downloads/Q22010MVR_PressRelease.pdf"
```

Answer (score 7):

```
path = path.substring(0, path.length() - 5);
```

Answer (score 6):

I am surprised to see that all the other answers (as of Sep 8, 2013) either involve counting the number of characters in the substring `".null"` or throw a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the substring is not found. Or both :(

I suggest the following:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String path = "file.txt";
        String extension = ".doc";

        int position = path.lastIndexOf(extension);

        if (position!=-1)
            path = path.substring(0, position);
        else
            System.out.println("Extension: "+extension+" not found");

        System.out.println("Result: "+path);
    }

}
```

If the substring is not found, nothing happens, as there is nothing to cut off. You won't get the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Also, you don't have to count the characters yourself in the substring.

Comment: This is really the best answer, as it can be adapted to suit any suffix without using a hard limit.

Answer (score 4):

If you like to remove last 5 characters, you can use:

```
path.substring(0,path.length() - 5)
```

( could contain off by one error ;) )

If you like to remove some variable string:

```
path.substring(0,path.lastIndexOf('yoursubstringtoremove));
```

(could also contain off by one error ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
if (s.size > 5) s.reverse.substring(5).reverse
```

BTW, this is Scala code. May need brackets to work in Java.

Comment: For the java version of this, you must create a `StringBuilder` based on the target string, and just as above, reverse it, delete the first 5 characters using `delete(0, 5)`, then reverse it again. Then turn it back into a string.