# Get path directory only and discard file in Java

Tags: java, file

How do we actually discard last file from java string and just get the file path directory?

Random Path input by user:

```
C:/my folder/tree/apple.exe
```

Desired output:

```
C:/my folder/tree/
```

closest solution i found is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125241/remove-the-last-chars-of-the-java-string-variable) . The answer from this forum only display last string acquired not the rest of it. I want to display the rest of the string.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The easiest and most failsafe (read: cross-platform) solution is to create a `File` object from the path.

Like this:

```
File myFile = new File( "C:/my folder/tree/apple.exe" );
// Now get the path
String myDir = myFile.getParent();
```

Comment: or use getParentFile() instead of getParent() to end up with a File object instead of a string.

Comment: Check similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28594297/get-the-directory-from-a-file-path-in-java-android

Answer (score 4):

Try that:

```
String path = "C:/my folder/tree/apple.exe";
path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Comment: you shall take into account that separator is nit garanted to be forward slash

Comment: Much better in my opinion - not making a file. Especially if the said file does not actually exist (yet). Worked perfectly for my needs.

Comment: You are not "making a file" by creating a `File` object. It's just the container for java.io functions.