# Get the directory from a file path in java (android)

Tags: java, android, path, directory

**Is there a function to get the directory part of a file path?**

so from

```
String a="/root/sdcard/Pictures/img0001.jpg";
```

you get

```
"/root/sdcard/Pictures"
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Yes. First, construct a [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) representing the image path:

```
File file = new File(a);
```

If you're starting from a relative path:

```
file = new File(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Then, [get the parent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParent%28%29):

```
String dir = file.getParent();
```

Or, if you want the directory as a `File` object,

```
File dirAsFile = file.getParentFile();
```

Comment: If you're using a relative path like `File f = new File("file.txt");` be aware that `f.getParent()` will return `null`, not the parent

Comment: How to extract path till "/root/sdcard/" or "/root/internal/" from file name ?

Comment: @hexafraction, JUST POSTED A QUESTION   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38381871/get-root-directory-i-e-external-or-external-sdcard-from-file-path

Answer (score 12):

A better way, use `getParent()` from `File` Class..

```
String a="/root/sdcard/Pictures/img0001.jpg"; // A valid file path 
File file = new File(a); 
String getDirectoryPath = file.getParent(); // Only return path if physical file exist else return null
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#getParent%28%29

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [FilenameUtils from Apache](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html). It provides you at least the following features for the example C:\dev\project\file.txt:

- the prefix - C:\
- the path - dev\project\
- the full path - C:\dev\project\
- the name - file.txt
- the base name - file
- the extension - txt

Answer (score 0):

I have got solution on this after 4 days, Please note following points while giving path to File class in Android(Java):

1. Use path for internal storage String path="/storage/sdcard0/myfile.txt";
2. path="/storage/sdcard1/myfile.txt";
3. mention permissions in Manifest file.

   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
4. First check file length for confirmation.
5. Check paths in ES File Explorer regarding sdcard0 & sdcard1 is this same or else......

e.g.

```
File file=new File(path);
long=file.length();//in Bytes
```