# get Root directory (i.e external or external sdcard) from file path

Tags: android, external, android-sdcard, android-file

I am facing a situation to calculate the free size of the currently selected primary memory(i.e external or external sdcard).
All i have is the file path in app specific folder like below

"/root/extsdcard/Android/data/com.a.b/files/img0001.jpg";

or

"/root/ext/Android/data/com.a.b/files/img0001.jpg";

How i can get the path "/root/extsdcard/" or "/root/ext/" respectively from above shown paths?

Comment: What is the code you use to show your current folder path?

Comment: @kabuto178,  i am using ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null) to store the file.

Comment: use Environment.getExternalDirectory() to get the folder path

Comment: @kabuto178, Can you please elaborate 'Environment.getExternalDirectory() ', there is no such method in Environment .

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns root of internal-storage. It has nothing to do with removable-storage (SD Card).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just mention "/" for root directory e.g. File

File f=new File("/");

```
String files[]=   f.list();
```

Comment: f.list() returns null for Android 11.

Comment: check you have initialized file object properly. it should not return null.