# How to delete a file using the path

Tags: android, file, android-intent, android-bitmap, mediastore

I'm building an app that allows the user to save the bitmap or share it without saving it.  The 2nd functionality doesn't quite work.  I understand that the app needs to save the file to the device before sharing it on a social media app so my idea was, immediately after the file was successfully shared, to automatically delete the file from the device.  I've build a delete method trying 2 different approaches and neither have worked:

First approach:

```
public void deleteFile(String path){
        File file = new File(path);
        try {
            file.getCanonicalFile().delete();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Second approach:

```
public void deleteFile(String path){
    File file = new File(path);
    boolean deleted = file.delete();
}
```

And I'm calling `deleteFile(String)` from the sharing method:

```
public void shareMeme(Bitmap bitmap) {
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Meme", null);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/*");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my Meme");
    getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Your Meme!"));

    deleteFile(path);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to your stated problem, `insertImage()` returns a string representation of a `Uri`. That `Uri` is not a file. Calling `getPath()` on it is pointless, and you cannot delete anything based on that path.

More broadly, if your intention is to delete the content right away:

- Do not put it in the `MediaStore`
- Do not share it, as you will be deleting it before the other app has a chance to do anything with it

If you want to share it, but then delete it:

- Do not put it in the `MediaStore`
- Delete it the next day, or in a few hours, or something, as you have no good way of knowing when the other app is done with the content

To share an image with another app without using the `MediaStore`:

- Save the image to a file in `getCacheDir()` (call that on a `Context`, such as an `Activity` or `Service`)
- Use `FileProvider` to make that file available to other apps

Beyond that:

- Do not use wildcard MIME types in `ACTION_SEND`. *You* are the one who is supplying the content to send. *You* know the actual MIME type. Use it.
- Note that there is no requirement for an `ACTION_SEND` activity to honor both `EXTRA_TEXT` and `EXTRA_STREAM`. Most seem to do so, but that behavior is outside of the `ACTION_SEND` specification.
- Note that `insertImage()` is deprecated on Android Q.

Comment: Say that the user wants to build & share more than 1 meme.  Is there a way to save them in the cache by overriding the previous one each time the user wishes to share it?

Comment: @AndrosAdrianopolos: Well, you could use the same filename each time. However, that may confuse the app(s) that are doing the sharing, so I do not recommend it. I would just check the cache on every app start and delete the image files that are older than X hours, for some value of X.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check if your `file` exists, (maybe you set the wrong path?). Then delete the `file`

```
        File file = new File(path);
        if (file.exists()){
            if (file.delete()) {
              Toast.makeText(this, "file Deleted :" + path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              } else {
              Toast.makeText(this, "file not Deleted :" + path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              }
        }
```

Comment: How do I get the `folder`?

Comment: @AndrosAdrianopolos check this answer how to get file folder path https://stackoverflow.com/a/28594333/5805371

Comment: The image is still saved.  When I deleted the code: `String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Meme", null);`, I was no longer able to share anything so this path DOES exist.

Comment: @AndrosAdrianopolos i updated the answer, do not check if the folder exists, only the file

Comment: Also.  Could it be that because `boolean deleted` is never called?

Comment: No error.  The code just goes back to saving a copy after sharing it.

Comment: @AndrosAdrianopolos may i suggest you share image without saving to `MediaStore`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191314/discussion-between-yuri-popiv-and-andros-adrianopolos).