# JavaScript concat string with backspace

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation, backspace

I have a function f similar to

```
function f(str){
    alert("abc"+str);
}
```

Now, I want to use JavaScript special charecter "\b" in such a way that I can choose if I want to display the hardcoded string "abc" or not. For example,

```
f("\b\b"+"yz"); //should output "ayz"
```

I tried the same, but it does not work. In other words, I want to concat a string with a backspace character so that I can remove last characters from the string.

Can we do this in JavaScript?

**EDIT**
The real code is too much big (its a HUGE 1 liner that concats many many strings). To map that in above example, we cannot edit the function f, so do whatever you want from outside function f.

Comment: Yes, we can do it. I can't "give teh codez" though. One way would be to analyze the `str` passed to the function, catch the `\b`s and do some string manipulation.

Comment: Very interesting question. I'm anxious to see the answer.

Comment: Pass an index where to concat. Negative index will slice earlier

Comment: Have you tried `f("\b\byz")`?

Comment: @DGH: Yes I did, it says "abcyz"

Comment: Interesting problem, but I think @mplungjan's solution is probably less cryptic and future programmers won't silently wish you a heinous death

Comment: @all, anything we can do from outside f ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that `\b` is just another character in the ASCII code. The special behaviour is only when implemented by some string reader, for example, a text terminal.

You will need to implement the backspace behaviour yourself.

```
function RemoveBackspaces(str)
{
    while (str.indexOf("\b") != -1)
    {
        str = str.replace(/.?\x08/, ""); // 0x08 is the ASCII code for \b
    }
    return str;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kendfrey/sELDv/

Use it like this:

```
var str = RemoveBackspaces(f("\b\byz")); // returns "ayz"
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, but I'm finding this doesn't execute right. For Example, `RemoveBackspaces("abcde\b\b"+"yz");` returns 'yz'

Comment: pretty cool fiddle, can you explain that regular expression a bit? I am too high to grasp that.

Comment: The regex matches any character (`.`) followed by a backspace (`\x08`), and replaces all those occurrences with an empty string.

Comment: pretty cool..thanks. I will accept this if I dont get an answer that does my problem from outside function f.

Comment: @hrishikeshp19 This does work outside the function. Just call it on the string that the function returns.

Comment: @KendallFrey: Nono...f returns nothing in real problem. See my edit. Actually, I have a huge line that concats many many strings. My string "str" is one of them, and I just want my string to eat up previous string.

Comment: @hrishikeshp19 Then concat the entire string together, including `\b`'s, and call the function on the result, on the next line.

Comment: I am prototying it. String.prototype.RemoveBackspaces =function(){} References: Kendall Frey.

Comment: I edited my code to take `\b`'s at the start of the string into account.

Comment: You can express `\b` as a backspace if you put it in a character class like `[\b]`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17438100/5743988)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I realized this may not be what the OP was looking for, but it is definitely the easier way to remove characters from the end of a string in most cases.

You should probably just use `string.substring` or `string.substr`, both of which return some portion of string. You can get the substring from 0 to the string's length minus 2, then concatenate that with "yz" or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I first checked some assumptions about \b in JS.

If you try this:

console.log('abc\b\byz');

You get the same answer of 'abcyz'.

This means, it is not a function of concatentation, but a fundamental error in the approach.

I would modify your approach to use SubString, then to take the index of \b and slice out the previous character.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
function f(str, abc){
   if(!abc) abc = "abc";
   if (str.indexOf("\b") != "undefined")
   {
       abc = abc.slice(0,-1);
       str = str.replace("\b","");
       f(str, abc);
   }
   else alert(abc+str);
}
```

and as an added bonus you get to use recursion!

note that this is a little slower than doing it this way:

```
function f(str){
    var count = 0;
    var abc = "abc";
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    { 
       if(str[i] = "\b") //at least i think its treated as one character...
       count++;
    }
    abc = abc.slice(0, count * -1);
    alert(abc+str);
}
```

Comment: Not yet, `f("abcde\b\b"+"yz");` returns "ababcdeyz"

Comment: Saem thing `f("ab\b\b"+"yz");` returns "ababyz"

Comment: @Wesley, but its not going to work like you're trying it. It should *only* delete from the stored *abc*. If the user wants it like that, I'll write it, but I don't entirely see the point in it, lol

Answer (score 0):

I'm processing the backspace `\b`, but it always has the ANSI erase in line `\x1B[K` after the `\b`s. So what I do is this:

```js
function applyBackspaces(str) {
  // Catch character + \b or character + \b\x1B[K and delete it
  const re = /.?[\u0008](\u001b\[K)?/
  while (re.test(str)) {    
    str = str.replace(re, "");
  }
  return str;
}

// wrote "up", backspace+erase, backspace+erase (used backspace key)
// wrote "ls", backspace+backspace+erase (used clear line command C-u)
// wrote uptime
applyBackspaces('up\b\x1B[K\b\x1B[Kls\b\b\x1B[Kuptime') // uptime
```