# Finding whole word only in Java string search

Tags: java, regex

I'm running into the problem of finding a searched pattern within a larger pattern in my Java program. For example, I'll try and find all `for` loops, but will stumble upon `formula`. Most of the suggestions I've found talk about using regular expression searches like

```
String regex = "\\b"+keyword+"\\b";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(searchString);
```

or some variant of this. The issue I'm running into is that I'm crawling through code, not a book-like text where there are spaces on either side of every word. For example, this will miss `for(`, which I would like to find. Is there another clever way to find whole words only?

Edit: Thanks for the suggestions. How about cases in which there the keyword starts on the first entry of the string? For example,

```
class Vec {
public:
   ...
};
```

where I'm searching for `class` (or alternatively `public`). The patterns suggested by Thanga, Austin Lee, npinti, and Kai Iskratsch do not work in this case. Any ideas?

Comment: If the `keyword` contain special symbols having special meaning in regex, to match them literally you'll need to escape them by preceding with slashes like ``\\b``

Comment: `\\bkeyword\\b"` will still match `for` in `for(` but it will skip `forum`

Comment: Not sure Im clear on this, but try matching ASCII values?

Comment: Once again `"\\b"+keyword+"\\b"` will work for all the cases described in question

Answer (score 2):

In your case, the *issue* is that the `\b` flag will look for punctuation marks, white spaces and the beginning or end of the string. An opening bracket does not fall within any of these categories, and is thus omitted.

The easiest way to fix this would be to replace `"\\b"+keyword+"\\b"` with `"[\\b(]"+keyword+"[\\b)]"`.

In regex syntax, the square brackets denote a set of which the regex engine will attempt to match any character it contains.

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438100/whats-the-use-of-the-b-backspace-regex) previous SO question, it would seem that `\b` and `[\b]` are not the same. Whilst `\b` represents a word boundary, `[\b]` represents a backspace character. To fix this, simply replace `"\\b"+keyword+"\\b"` with `"(\b|\()"+keyword+"(\b|\))"`.

Comment: i think you will have to escape the brakets too. also depending on what language the program code is you will have to add more exceptions. an option could be [\\b\\W]+keyword+[\\b\\W] (\w matches any non word character)

Comment: No need of `[\b(]` as `(` is not considered a word character.

Answer (score 1):

Regex should match 0 or more chars. The below code change will fix the issue

```
String regex = ".*("+keyword+").*";
```

Comment: This does not find anything

Comment: @mjswartz I edited my answer. This works for your use cases including "class". I tested  this

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your regex to search for multiple characters afterwords, for example 
[^\w]+"for"+[^\w]  using the Pattern class in Java.

For your reference:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will have to adapt your regex to all the possible patterns it can find. But considering your actually dealing with code, you are better of building a [parser/tokenizer](http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=525) for that language, or using one that already exists. Then all you have to do is run through the tokens to find the the ones you want.