# How to allow only certain characters in an input field

Tags: regex, typescript

I want to allow input in a text box only if it is a number, a decimal point or a backspace.

I have the following regex that matches numbers or the decimal point. How can I also accept a backspace? I know `[\b]` matches the backspace but I'm having trouble adding it to my existing set.

```
/^[0-9\.]+$/
```

Comment: I want to allow input in a text box only if it is a number, a decimal point or a backspace.

Comment: `\b` does not match backspace, it matches [word boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regex)

Comment: I believe `[\b]` only [works if the backspace ASCII character already exists in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17438159/8967612). I don't know typescript, so hopefully, someone will help you but it looks like you want to allow/disallow some key-presses, not characters. Moreover, that line you just deleted from the question body is very relevant to what you're trying to do. I would encourage you to rollback the last edit. Relevant information belongs to the post itself, not the comments.

Comment: @Chase I thought so too at first but turns out `\b` in a character class (i.e., `[\b]`) does match an ASCII backspace character. See the link in my last comment for more info.

Comment: @41686d6564 Apologize, That line seemed redundant as I already explained that exact sentence in my question.

Comment: You can try its unicode `\u{8}`

Comment: Try `/^[0-9.\x08]+$/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, unfortunately `/^[0-9.\x08]+$/.test("Backspace")` isn't returning true

Comment: `/^[0-9.\x08]+$/.test("\b")` returns `true`

Answer (score -1):

Just add it to your character set, no?

```
const test = /^[0-9\.\b]+$/.test("1.6\u0008")

console.log(test)
```

Comment: It has already been sugguested.