# Backspace \b not working when included in alphabetic regex in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

The following blocks out all chars which are not either alphabetic or backspace (`\b`), but you can see that the Backspace doesn't work and is also filtered out. Why is that?

```js
$('#field').keydown(function(e) {
  if (!/^[A-Za-z\b]$/i.test(e.key)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="field" />
```

Comment: `[A-Za-z\b]` doesn't this have the backspace char in the class ? Have you tried `[A-Za-z\x08]` ? Or possibly even `if (/^[^A-Za-z\x08]$/i.test(e.key))` Because nothing says bogus like when regex doesn't support the backspace control character..

Comment: witness: https://regex101.com/r/HWh8Ea/1
https://regex101.com/r/MssBzT/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `event.key` value for the backspace key is `"Backspace"`.

```js
$('#field').keydown(function(e) {
  if (!/^([a-z]|Backspace)$/i.test(e.key)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="field" />
```

Comment: But inside character classes `\b` is a backspace: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17438159/1005607 . This is used inside a character class, isn't it?

Comment: @geneb. That's true, but `event.key` is not a literal backslash character for backspace, but the string `"Backspace"`.

Comment: Ah, so that was the issue. thanks.

Comment: One more question. I need to allow all navigation chars: Backspace, Delete, Arrow Keys, and Home and Delete. In other words, all alphabetic + navigation, but nothing else. Is there a simple way to accomplish this? Or do I have to enumerate each key?

Comment: @geneb. Unfortunately, you would have to list out the keys apart from the alphabetic ones.

Comment: And yet another MS imposed penalty, or is it? The only way. Might as well jump off a cliff.