# PHP concatenation override

Tags: php, string, concatenation

Is it possible to change a concatened string, with a variable in the string?

```
  $x = 'XXX' . $y;
```

Is there a way to have $x contain 'XXY', without changing this?

What do I need to set in $y for this? Does there exist something like a "remove previous character"?

EDIT:

Maybe i didnt made myself crystal clear:

$y needs to be a string, no functions or anything. Its due to discover an exploit...

Comment: like a reg expression?

Comment: Related: [javascript version of what this question is getting at](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891653/javascript-concat-string-with-backspace)

Comment: Little context or a bit more information would be good. In the given code sample is not exactly clear what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Where are you wanting to use this?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Through a microprocessor – *Mornin' Sam*

Comment: @Fred-ii- *ba-dump-bump!* heh *Mornin' Ralph*

Comment: @JayBlanchard *Bah-dah-bump Kah-Rraaaash!!!* < cymbal crash sound - *salut Sam*

Comment: If you cannot use functions then there is no way to do what you're asking in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

```
$x = substr("XXX", 0, -1) . $y;
```

In light of your edit, I don't think you can do what you want the way you want it to happen.

Comment: you are changing the value of $x, not $y. I think the author just wants to see if there are some gotchas in PHP string concatenation implementation.

Comment: I think the OP wants to change `$x` @LaurynasTretjakovas "so that `$x` would contain XXY"

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of, but you can use [`substr_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php):

```
$x = substr_replace($x, $y, -1);
```

If you want to replace the exact number of characters in `$y` at the end of `$x`:

```
$x = substr_replace($x, $y, -(strlen($y));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the value of $y to a backspace character plus 'Y':

```
$y = chr(8) . 'Y';
```

Comment: This doesn't work, the result is 'XXXY' when the OP wants 'XXY' [EXAMPLE](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/vgat-6z0w)

Comment: This *does* work in the CLI we just don't know what the OP's intent is.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$y = chr(8).'Y';
$x = 'XXX' . $y;
```

`chr(8)` should give you a backspace character.

Comment: `var_dump($x)` is `string(5) "XXXY"`

Comment: It doesn't work - [EXAMPLE](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/vgat-6z0w)

Comment: PHPFiddle is probably sanitizing the characters, try running it locally. it works for me.

Comment: I ran it locally and it didn't work.

Comment: What's the php version?

Comment: 5.3.3 on one server, 5.6.2 on another. PHP fiddle doesn't sanitize stuff like this. What version are you running?

Comment: Are you outputing the data in browser? or CLI?

Comment: Browser. Let me try CLI.

Comment: I assume the backspace escape sequence won't be recognized by the browser, only by CLI.

Comment: It works in the CLI. Unfortunately we do not know how the OP wants to use.

Comment: It has to work in non-cli but you exactly understood what i want to achieve! I cant use functions $y got to be a string.