# Outputting Escape Characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I think it is a bit simple question but I couldn't find my answer neither on Stackoverflow nor Google. Here is my question. I want to output strings with escape characters. I have used the method document.getElementIdBy().

Here is my example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="example1"></p><br>
    <p id="example2"></p><br>
    <p id="example3"></p><br>
    <p id="example4"></p><br>
    <script>
        var x = "\"ABC\""
        var y = "\'ABC\'"
        var z = "ABC\nDEF"
        var t = "ABC\bDEF"
        document.getElementById("example1").innerHTML=x;
        document.getElementById("example2").innerHTML=y;
        document.getElementById("example3").innerHTML=z;
        document.getElementById("example4").innerHTML=t;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The first two works fine. The third one doesn't create a new line and the fourth one doesn't crate a backspace. I assume that the variable z is like this

```
ABC
DEF
```

If I write this into a p element, it must show up like this: ABC DEF. Therefore I can understand why it doesn't appear as I expected (If I style the p element with white-space:pre it works as I expected)

However I wonder why \b escape character doesn't work as expected. Actually I was expecting the output to be: ABDEF (without C). There may be some logic similar to the upper one but I cannot find. Can someone explain why it doesn't work?

Comment: Probably the way browsers handle input in a different way than terminals - the new line in HTML is achieved using a line break tag (`<br>`), not sure exactly what happens with the backspace, it might be just trying to move the cursor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891653/javascript-concat-string-with-backspace

Comment: Yup, I was right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891653/javascript-concat-string-with-backspace

Answer (score 0):

I think these chars are just stripped from HTML, you could achieve what you want by replacing \n with `<br/>`

e.g.

```
document.getElementById("example3").innerHTML=z.replace("\n","<br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

> The third one doesn't create a new line

New lines in text are ignored in HTML tags. They are rendered as a `space`. Use `<pre>` tags to keep formatting:

```
<pre id="example3"></pre>
```

Or add `<p>` tags instead of new lines:

```
var z = "<p>ABC</p><p>DEF</p>"
```

Or `<br>`

```
var z = "ABC<br>DEF"
```

> the fourth one doesn't crate a backspace

Do not pretty sure that HTML/JS supports `\b`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but merely repeats what OP has already stated... OP is looking for the explanation of backspace behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

new line (`\n`) doesn't generate new line in html.

so if you write:

```
<p>first line
second line</p>
```

you will get:first line second line.

so to write `\n` to html you must convert it to `<br>`.

```
document.getElementById("example3").innerHTML=z.replace(/\n/g,'<br>');
```

this regular expression replaces all `\n` with `<br>`.

and `\b` is just character with code `8`. its special behavior occurs only when you send it to an input or text box.

Comment: `\b` is **most definitely not** written as it is.

Comment: Can you show a working example. When I change the tags of the first element to textarea it doesn't change.

Comment: I mean when you send `\b` as an input from keyboard to textarea(when you click backspace). textarea handles it and then instead of append `\b`it removes a character.