# How can I draw EditText on canvas in View class

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-canvas

I'm developing an android game and I need to load player nick to save score with nick but I don't know how to **draw EditText on canvas.**
**Is that possible?** And if not is there another way to get user input like String?

Comment: Yes it is check this answer is similar to what you want to do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892916/use-edittext-on-canvas

Comment: Thanks for help but that solution didn't work for me