# How to remove the last character from a string in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have a string like below and am trying to remove the last character from that string. can someone please help on this

*what if I have a lengthy string and I want to only remove the last character of my string.*

Example: "city": "Winston Salem","state": "NC","zip": "27127","country": " "}}

and I want to only remove the last '}'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the last character from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438612/how-to-remove-the-last-character-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Use a String method like replace:

```
String newString = oldString.replace("}}", "}")
```

if that´s case or another one; you can use anywhere of methods of String API only if casts to String